# Why is the nav CSS behaving differently on different pages?

Tags: css, google-chrome, nav

Why is the navigation bar behaving differently on different pages? They have the same css rules.

http://www.columbia.edu/~mmp2181/Megha/wwm.html (navigation bar is glued to the top) http://www.columbia.edu/~mmp2181/Megha/ (gap between top of page and the header)

Note: I'm specifically asking about its behavior on Google Chrome

```
> header nav, contactheader nav, wwmheader nav {width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin:           >0;  padding:15px 0 20px; background: #FDFDFD; border-top: 1px solid #f6f6f6; position: fixed; z->index: 7;
```

> box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
>     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
>     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
>   }

Comment: On the page with the page you have an image in your code, right after the opening body tag, (http://www.columbia.edu/images/photos/meghahorizontal2cropb.jpeg) that is 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy one ;-) There's a `img` hiding in the top of your `<body>` tag.

`<img src="/images/photos/meghahorizontal2cropb.jpeg" height="0" width="0">`

Just remove the little fella and everything is gonna be alright.

Cheers
Gion